# How to insert or save given values in select list using many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form which the user need to fill up. It has a different input for the user **title** and **content** belongs to **documents** table and recipient input belongs to **users** table. I already given the values on my recipient form based on my **users** table records.

**Problem**:

I need to insert the user's choice in my select list into **recipients_received_documents** (junction table). and also the **user_id** that currently login.

Form:

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route('document.create')}}">

            <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "title" class = "control-label">Title:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "title" class = "form-control">

            </div>

            <div class = "form-group">

                <label for = "recipient" class = "control-label">To:</label>
                <select onChange = "showUserOptions(this)" name = "recipient[]" multiple class = "form-control" id = "myUserList">

                    @foreach ($result as $list)
                        <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
                    @endforeach

                </select>

            </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
                <textarea id="content" name = "content"></textarea>

            </div>


            <div class = "form-group">
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" onclick="get_editor_content()">Send</button>
            </div>

            <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

Migration:

**users_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('remember_token');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**documents_table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**recipients_received_documents** Junction table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recipients_received_documents',function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('senderUserId')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('recipientUserId')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('docu_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('senderUserId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('recipientUserId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('docu_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
}
```

DocumentController:

```
public function getDocuments()
{
    $result = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

    return view ('document.create')->with('result', $result);
}

public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'recipient' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);

    $title = $request['title'];
    $content = $request['content'];

    $document = new Document();
    $document->title = $title;
    $document->content = $content;

    $document->save();

    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

I'm little bit confuse here I don't know how can I save my `recipient` form into junction table because this is belong to **documents** table. Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think this link could help you, was handy for me when I needed to learn pivoting: http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Also, in your model to actually get the current Authed user ID, you can use Eloquent Model Events: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events

**recipients_received_documents** model should have the following added *(keep in mind that if your model is under any namespace, you'll need to add `use Auth;` below your namespace declaration)*

```
public static function boot(){
    parent::boot(); // <-- Don't forget this

    self::creating(function($model){
        $model->auth_id = Auth::user()->id;
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Gonna read this bro. Thanks for this. In your example. I need to add that in my Model for able to get the currently user?

Comment: Exactly, it's like a `constructor`, althought I actually forgot something, so re-check the added line :+1: Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain to me the use of this syntax? Because it's new to me. So I can have idea :)

Comment: The first link will cover up everything, as for Model Events it's fairly simple to understand, definitely give it a read. :+1: